# What is the meaning of synchronous and asynchronous requests in Linux Kyber I/O Scheduler?

Tags: kernel, io, nvme

While studying I/O Schedulers, I've read some documents for I/O Schedulers in Linux Kernel.
Especially for Kyber Scheduler, there are some confusing things.
In the articles in following link ( https://lwn.net/Articles/720675/ ),
Kyber Scheduler has two primary queues, one for synchronous requests and one for asynchronous requests.
In that article, it says

> A process issuing a read request is typically unable to proceed until that request completes and the data is available, so such requests are seen as synchronous.

I thought synchronous and asynchronous requests depends on CPU and device driver, not kinds of I/O operations.

Any ideas for this question?

Answer (score 1):

That would be more like "conceptually synchronous", or perhaps "synchronous at a higher level of abstraction than the one you were thinking about". A program reads data in order to process it somehow, so until it gets that data, it cannot do the processing: so the reading must be a synchronous operation.

Write requests, on the other hand, can be deferred, as long as other operations will "see" the data as equivalent to written to the final destination. In other words, any read operations must first check if a modified version of the data they're about to read exists in the write cache, and if so, "read" from the cache instead.